# Prove that $\frac{2-2a^2}{1+a^2}+\frac{1-b^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{1-c^2}{1+c^2} \leq \frac{9}{4}$

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $ab+bc+ca=1$. Prove that
$$\frac{2-2a^2}{1+a^2}+\frac{1-b^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{1-c^2}{1+c^2} \leq \frac{9}{4}$$
I find when the equality occurs at $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}},b=c=\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$ but I don't know how to prove it. I tried to use the equality $1+a^2=\left(a+b\right)\left(a+c\right)$ but it seems to be more difficult than the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also the following reasoning.

We need to prove that
$$\frac{2(1-a^2)}{1+a^2}-2+\frac{1-b^2}{1+b^2}-1+\frac{1-c^2}{1+c^2}-1\leq\frac{9}{4}-4$$ or
$$\frac{2a^2}{1+a^2}+\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{c^2}{1+c^2}\geq\frac{7}{8}.$$
Now, by C-S
$$\frac{2a^2}{1+a^2}+\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{c^2}{1+c^2}=\frac{a^2}{\frac{1+a^2}{2}}+\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{c^2}{1+c^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\frac{1+a^2}{2}+1+b^2+1+c^2}=\frac{2(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+2b^2+2c^2+5(ab+ac+bc)}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$16(a+b+c)^2\geq7(a^2+2b^2+2c^2+5(ab+ac+bc))$$ or
$$9a^2-3(b+c)a+2b^2+2c^2-3bc\geq0,$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$(b+c)^2-4(2b^2+2c^2-3bc)\leq0$$ or
$$(b-c)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.

Comment: @RuaSun You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=x$, $b=3y$ and $c=3z$.

Thus, after homogenization and full expanding we need to prove that:
$$3x^2y+3x^2z+y^2x+3y^2z+z^2x+3z^2y\geq14xyz,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$3x^2y+3x^2z+y^2x+3y^2z+z^2x+3z^2y\geq14\sqrt[14]{x^{6+6+1+1}y^{3+2+6+3}z^{3+3+2+6}}=14xyz.$$
Done!